# Count TOP 5, Count all else as "Other"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table of PCs and would like to get a count of the top PC manufacturers. Since the data will be displayed in a pie chart and there are currently ~45 different manufacturers, I'd like to get the count of the top 5, then combine everything else into 'Other'.

The following query will return a count of all PCs by manufacturer:

```
SELECT 
    f_assetmanufacturer,
    COUNT(*) as 'PCs'
FROM tb_assets 
GROUP BY f_assetmanufacturer
```

Sample output of the query above is:

```
f_assetmanufacturer    PCs
-----------------------------
Dell                   100
HP                     50
Lenovo                 25
Acer                   24
Toshiba                23
Microsoft              20
Equus                  20
Thinix                 20
Advantech              20
```

Desired output would be as follows:

```
f_assetmanufacturer    PCs                   f_assetmanufacturer    PCs
-----------------------------                -----------------------------
Dell                   100                   Dell                   100
HP                     50                    Other                  100
Lenovo                 25          or        HP                     50
Acer                   24                    Lenovo                 25    
Toshiba                23                    Acer                   24
Other                  100                   Toshiba                23
```

How can I select only the Top 5 manufacturers and combine all remaining manufacturers into an 'Other' category in order to simplify the output in a pie chart?

Comment: Why not just display the top 5 and aggregate the rest in the application layer.... almost every chart function allows this, to display the top N percent or N top items and roll up the rest.

Comment: I most definitely can do that if a SQL solution isn't concise/clear/easy/efficient. I, however, don't have a charting function that will do this for me and it would have to be written custom, which may add more overhead than a SQL solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN seqnum <= 5 THEN f_assetmanufacturer ELSE 'Other' END) as assetmanufacturer,
       SUM(PCs) as PCs
FROM (SELECT f_assetmanufacturer, COUNT(*) as PCs,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tb_assets 
      GROUP BY f_assetmanufacturer
     ) a
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN seqnum <= 5 THEN f_assetmanufacturer ELSE 'Other' END)
ORDER BY PCs DESC;
```

Note:  You might want to use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`, depending on how you want to handle ties in the "fifth" place.

Comment: This is very clear and concise, thank you. I hadn't considered anything even remotely similar to this.

Comment: Very wise to raise the issue of ties.  +1 for that alone

Answer (score 1):

You could use CTEs to build the two sets and union the data together like below:

```
with top5
as (
SELECT top 5
    f_assetmanufacturer,
    COUNT(*) as 'PCs'
FROM tb_assets 
GROUP BY f_assetmanufacturer
order by 2 desc)
,other
as(
select 'Other',
    COUNT(*) as 'PCs'
FROM tb_assets a
where not exists (select 'ne' from top5 t where a.f_assetmanufacturer = t.f_assetmanufacturer)))

select * from top5
union all
select * from other
```